# I want to get sendtime as an input in smtplib

Tags: python, input, smtplib

I am coding a program that sends scheduled emails, but I require the time in code, like this:

```
send_time = dt.datetime(2021,12,23,4,30,0)
```

I would like to get this send time as an input from user
like:

```py
a = int(input("enter the time:"))
send_time = dt.datetime(a)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a good candidate for [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)

The official documentation can be a bit overwhelming. [Here’s a link to a tutorial](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strptime) that explains clearly how to use the `strptime` method.

> ### How strptime() works?
>
> The strptime() class method takes two arguments:
>
> string (that be converted to datetime) format code
> Based on the string and format code used, the method > returns its equivalent datetime object.

In your case, if You could try this:

```py
a = int(input("enter date and time in dd/mm/yyyy H:M:S:"))
send_time = datetime.strptime(a, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

One way to assume today’s date and only add the time:

```py
today = datetime.date.today()
a = input("enter the time HH:MM:SS: ")
# convert input to datetime and replace with today’s year, month and day
timetoday = datetime.datetime.strptime(a, "%H:%M:%S").replace(year=today.year, month=today.month, day=today.day)
```